# ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root

Tags: c#, .net

I have get this error when I run and debug my project,

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one  element
> allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the
> root  elemen

But the project also build correctly and successfully,,

My project is about soap web service and calling the api,,

whats the solution of this issue?

Comment: Read the error message carefully, have a look at the config file and see if violates one of the mentioned constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error it said that the order of configuration in web.config file is not correct,,
you must use config section as the first segment of configuration block and after that the error will be solved,,,

the source code of you maybe is like below

```
<configuration>
    
    <configSections>
        
        <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx"/>

        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx" requirePermission="false"/>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx">
            
        </sectionGroup>


    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="xxxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>


</configuration>
```

you can use the above code sample for solving your problem

best regard

Comment: I found that I should noticed to order of configuration